# Length of specific substring

Tags: java, c#, regex, maxlength, digit

I check if my string begins with number using

```
if(RegEx(IsMatch(myString, @"\d+"))) ...
```

If this condition holds I want to get the length of this "numeric" substring that my string begins with.

I can find the length checking if every next character is a digit beginning from the first one and increasing some counter. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Can you assume anything about the character after the "numeric" substring? For instance, will the string always look similar to : 1234abc, or is this possible : 12345 with no character afterwards?

Comment: @ademing2, well, it's a mathematical expression, but u can never be sure that the user inputs it correctly ))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check if my string **begins** with number, you need to use pattern `^\d+`.

```
string pattern = @"^\d+";
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(myString, pattern);
if(mc.Count > 0)
{
  Console.WriteLine(mc[0].Value.Length);
}
```

Comment: +1 MatchCollection seems safer than just Match. Then you can get the largest length string of all the values.

Comment: @ademing2: How many matches do you expect there to be that start at the beginning of the string, given greedy matching?

Comment: @user1215106: But adds complexity for the *immediate* needs. Given the requirement for a single match, I still think using Match is a better fit for the current requirements.

Comment: @JonSkeet - what if `myString` is multi-line input?

Comment: @user1215106: Then we'd need to know what the requirements are. But you seem to be making things more complicated without any indication that we *need* them to be complicated.

Answer (score 6):

Well instead of using `IsMatch`, you should *find* the match:

```
// Presumably you'll be using the same regular expression every time, so
// we might as well just create it once...
private static readonly Regex Digits = new Regex(@"\d+");

...

Match match = Digits.Match(text);
if (match.Success)
{
    string value = match.Value;
    // Take the length or whatever
}
```

Note that this *doesn't* check that the digits occur at the start of the string. You could do that using `@"^\d+"` which will anchor the match to the beginning. Or you could check that `match.Index` was 0 if you wanted...

Answer (score 3):

Your regex checks if your string contains a sequence of one or more numbers. If you want to check that it starts with it you need to anchor it at the beginning:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(myString, @"^\d+");
if (m.Success)
{
    int length = m.Length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to a regular expression, you can use extension methods:

```
int cnt = myString.TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit).Count();
```

If there are no digits in the beginning of the string you will naturally get a zero count. Otherwise you have the number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just checking `IsMatch`, get the match so you can get info about it, like the length:

```
var match = Regex.Match(myString, @"^\d+");
if (match.Success)
{
    int count = match.Length;
}
```

Also, I added a `^` to the beginning of your pattern to limit it to the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you break out your code a bit more, you can take advantage of [Regex.Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx):

```
var length = 0;

var myString = "123432nonNumeric";
var match = Regex.Match(myString, @"\d+");

if(match.Success)
{
    length = match.Value.Length;
}
```